# Why does the token returned by LogonUser() in Win x64 not belong to LOCAL group?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, winapi

I have a piece of code that calls LogonUser() followed by CreateProcessAsUser(). In Win32, the resulting process belongs to a user (say, TESTDOMAIN\user1) who belongs to the LOCAL group. However, in x64, the process owner does not belong to LOCAL. The owner still belongs to all other groups (Authenticated Users, Everyone, etc.)

Does anyone know if this is a documented behavior change? Or am I supposed to put some special flag in x64 when calling LogonUser()?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the difference is between 64-bit and 32-bit?  Where is LOCAL defined?  Is it defined on both machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed this behavior with MSDN support. They cited security reasons for the behavior change.

Answer (score 0):

In no version of MS Windows is there such a thing as a group named "LOCAL".
Read this
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726980.aspx
Then try being more specific, and correct in your use of the names and terminology.

Please provide more context also:
The specific operating system are you using?
Is the caller of CreateProcessAsUser a Service?

Comment: Open your ProcessExplorer, choose any process, see the Security. Is there no LOCAL?

Comment: The `Local` well-known SID, S-1-2-0, is documented in passing in the [MSDN page on SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd302645.aspx).  I have no idea what it's for, however; so it's probably best for everyone to avoid using it unless someone can find further documentation somewhere. :-)